# How to improve Magento Ajax Performance?

Tags: ajax, performance, magento

I'm currently developing an ajax plugin for Magento and wonder how I can improve it's performance. Let's start with an example. I want to show the number of items in the shopping cart on an external page. Or a page that has been rendered via full page caching and needs a to update the cart info via a JavaScript Ajax request.

*For that I see two ways of doing it.*

**Making use of a Magento Controller stripped down to the minimum**

```
class AFCustom_CartInfo_AjaxController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

    public function indexAction() {
      header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
      header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
      header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

      $out = $this->__('My Cart');
      if (Mage::helper('core')->isModuleOutputEnabled('Mage_Checkout')) {
        $count = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getSummaryQty() ? Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getSummaryQty()
            : MAGE::helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount();
        if ($count == 1) {
          $out = $this->__('My Cart (%s item)', $count);
        } elseif ($count > 0) {
          $out = $this->__('My Cart (%s items)', $count);
        } else {
          $out = $this->__('My Cart');
        }
      }
      echo $out;
      exit;
    }
}
```

As you can see I exit the code in the controller and don't user render layout. However the requests are still taking quite long. I assume because it has to load the whole Framework. Are there ways to just load the minimum requirements of Magento to execute the controller? Would it be able to disable the layout engine as it is not needed? How would I do that? What other modules could I switch off?

**Observer to Update Session**
A second solution would be to have an observer to listen for changes in the shopping cart (checkout_cart_save_after) and update an PHP session variable. Which could be read out in a small custom PHP script. However, I'm not sure how I could easily patch into the same session mechanism as Magento uses? I figure that it might not be advisable to directly use $_SESSION as an Magento session might be handled elsewhere.

What would you do? Any pointers are appreciated?

Many thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is anything like load only minimum requirements because the request will pass the whole Magento stack. I'd suggest trying out something like APC to speed up Magento in general. If it's not hosted on an SSD there is quite a bit of HDD file loading delay when running any big php framework - the caches can speed things up substantially.

If this is still too slow you might hack a solution that uses another $_SESSION just to store cart data and return that with a plain ajax.php - though this is tricky because you shouldn't use the Magento session directly as you said.

Answer (score 0):

You can cache your requests and put the data to cache in observer observing the cart change, then you just have to request the block or whatever you cache there and echo the output.

Point being that you pre-populate the output to cache not requesting it over and over.

Comment: So it is quicker to load my output string from cache than to check the carts content? Wouldn't be the cart already cached? You're suggesting that it is still quicker to implement a observer to have to save the string in the cache and simple read that cache item and response that in my controller.

Comment: yes it is faster as you prepare the data for reading in to cache and then reading from cache. Instead of reading it from the object making lot of mysql queries or invoking the layout etc. It's like going to store and reading the sign that is placed on window: "We have 45 items of sh*t in stock" instead of going to store without the sign and ask the seller "How much sh*t do you got here?" and seller goes to stock and reads the stuff, comes back and tells you "we have 45 items of sh*t in stock" and then you ask again, and seller is like: "oh noes I have to go and check again"